# Sending a file via PUT to codeigniter REST_Controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, rest, curl, put

I'm trying to upload some files to a web-server via PUT.

I'm using Phil Sturgeon's REST library on the server side.

The client is a PHP application using curl to generate the requests.

```
...
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PUT, true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_INFILE,$fp);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_INFILESIZE,$fsize);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
$headarray = array();
if ($api_key)
    $headarray[] = 'X-API-KEY:'.$api_key;
$headarray[] = "Content-Type: application/octet-stream";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headarray);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_exec($ch);
...
```

The data is being received. 
However when I look at $this->put() on the server side, I get an array which looks like my input file got parsed. I would like the entire file to be available as one string, as raw data.

I tried to use  `fopen("php://input", "r");` instead, but it's blank. Presumably this has already been consumed by the REST library.

I haven't written a PUT request before using curl, so maybe something is wrong on that side of things.

Is there an alternative to $this->put() which will give me the raw input rather than an array.

It seems that I may have to put my file into a parameter, if so, how to do that with curl when I'm using CURLOPT_INFILE? I want to be able to send large files without running into php's memory limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What a mess... you can see the offender here:

REST_Controller.php - line ~950

```
protected function _parse_put()
{
    // It might be a HTTP body
    if ($this->request->format)
    {
        $this->request->body = file_get_contents('php://input');
    }

    // If no file type is provided, this is probably just arguments
    else
    {
        parse_str(file_get_contents('php://input'), $this->_put_args);
    }

}
```

The `if` would do exactly what you want: dump the raw contents into `$this->request->body`. This `if` isn't hit, though, so it does the `parse_str` which stupidly adds the underscores and puts the result **as the key** in the `$this->put()` array with no value (so `array_flip` doesn't work either). Wow.

I can't seem to figure out a way to get the library to find `$this->request->format` true; if you add the content type you are using or change the content type in the cURL headers, we get a stack trace along the lines of

```
Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Format class does not support conversion from "stream".' in /Users/mycpu/Sites/ci-rest/application/libraries/Format.php:51
Stack trace:
#0 /Users/mycpu/Sites/ci-rest/application/libraries/Format.php(31): Format->__construct('Lorem ipsum Ut ...', 'stream')
#1 /Users/mycpu/Sites/ci-rest/application/libraries/REST_Controller.php(251): Format->factory('Lorem ipsum Ut ...', 'stream')
#2 /Users/mycpu/Sites/ci-rest/system/core/CodeIgniter.php(308): REST_Controller->__construct()
#3 /Users/mycpu/Sites/ci-rest/index.php(202): require_once('/Users/mycpu...')
#4 {main}
  thrown in /Users/mycpu/Sites/ci-rest/application/libraries/Format.php on line 51
```

The easiest way I can see to solve this is to change the `parse_str` line to something like

```
array_push($this->_put_args, file_get_contents('php://input'));
```

then the unadulterated `php://input` will be available via

```
$p = $this->put();
$p[0];//contents of file
```

Hopefully this will at least help get you going in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts in this. I tried something along the same lines, messing around with request->body, but I wasn't sure if I had formatted my request correctly in the first place.

Comment: I finally got around to looking at this again. I added the following code to libraries/Format.php to get rid of the exception `private function _from_binary($string){
  return $string;
 }`

Now the contents are available through $this->request->body, or $this->put() as in your answer above.